# Galería de imágenes flexbox se desordena cuando agrego etiqueta <a> las imagenes deben quedar una al lado de otra y estan una abajo de otra

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Las imagenes deberian estar una al lado de otra, pero cuando agregué , la galeria se desordena y las imagenes quedan una abajo de otra.

```
.productos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.productos img {
  width: 27%;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #8E8787;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="productos">
  <a href="tabla-zapato.html"><img id="zoom3" src="imagenes/zapato.jpg" alt="sandalia"></a>
  <a href="tabla-sobre.html"><img id="zoom3" src="imagenes/sobre.jpg" alt="sobre"></a>
  <a href="tabla-aros.html"><img id="zoom3" src="imagenes/aros.jpg" alt="aros"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: revisaste cual es el tamaño de tu etiqueta a. puede que ocupe todo el width.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que antes los estilos de la clase productos eran aplicados al contenedor de las imágenes (`<div>`). Al agregar las etiquetas `<a>`, los contenedores de las imágenes son ellas y ya no `<div>`. Hay que aplicar los mismos estilos para ellas agregando a tu css lo siguiente:

```
.productos>a{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

O combinando

```
.productos, .productos>a{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```